# Animations skipping with multiple touch inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile-safari, gsap

I am writing an HTML game that is designed for tablets using greensock as the animation engine and jQuery for event binding. The current build can be seen at http://gregbatha.com/battleblocks/. It works by having each block as a div that receives a touch event and is moved around using greensock.

It is working well in general, however since it is two player there are two people tapping blocks rapidly at any given time. When two people tap within milliseconds of each other, it causes the animations to lag or skip. Does anyone know why this is?

My event-handling code can be seen below

```
$('.block').bind( touchEnd, function(){
    $this = $(this);
    var thisX = $this.data('x');
    var thisY = $this.data('y');

    console.log(thisX+", "+thisY);

    var player = grid[thisY][thisX].player;

    //if this player currently hasn't selected any blocks, select this one
    if(players[player].selectedBlock == null && !$this.hasClass('group')){
        //set this block as the currently selected block
        selectBlock(thisX, thisY);

    }else{
        //otherwise react accordingly

        //if the player selected a selectable block, switch the currently selected block with this new one
        if($this.hasClass('group')){
            explodeGroup(thisX, thisY);
        }else if($this.hasClass('selectable')){
            $('.player'+player).removeClass('selected selectable');
            switchBlocks(players[player].selectedBlock.x, players[player].selectedBlock.y, thisX, thisY, function(){
                checkGroups();
            });
            players[player].selectedBlock = null;


        }else if($this.hasClass('selected')){
            //if player selects currently selected block, unselect it
            $('.player'+player).removeClass('selected selectable');
            players[player].selectedBlock = null;
        }else{
            //if the player did not select a selectable block for switching, make this new block the selected one
            $('.player'+player).removeClass('selected selectable');
            selectBlock(thisX, thisY);
        }
    }

} );
```